# C# playlist realization

Tags: c#, .net, media

I'm looking for a simple C# solution to manage a playlist. Not the actual playback functionality, just adding, removing, reordering stuff and so on.

Does such code exist?

Comment: In general, or for windows media player or for flash or what?

Comment: It's going to be a custom WinForms player, but I think it doesn't make any difference. Any general solution should be fine.

Comment: What are your constraints on what it needs to do? Is it a fixed playlist that loops (or doesn't)? Is there some algorithm that needs to determine what to include or play next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your playlist has items like this in it:

```
public class PlaylistItem { 
    public String Artist { get; set; }
    public String Album { get; set; }
    public String Song { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Length { get; set; }
    public String SongFile { get; set; }
}
```

Then a `List<PlaylistItem>` should do:

```
var mySong = new PlayListItem { 
    Artist = "LMFAO", 
    Album = "Sorry for Party Rocking", 
    Song = "Sexy and I Know It", 
    Length = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,3,19,0), 
    SongFile = "C:\LMFAO.mp3" };
var myPlaylist = new List<PlaylistItem>();

// Add an item:
myPlayList.Add(mySong);

// Remove an item:
myPlayList.Remove(mySong);

// Reorder (assuming you've added some other items):
var song = myPlayList[0];
myPlayList[0] = myPlayList[1];
myPlayList[1] = song;
```

etc...

If you want, you can even subclass `List<T>` to add your own information, like which song is currently playing:

```
public class Playlist : List<PlaylistItem> {
    public Int32 CurrentSong { get; set; }
}
```